# UpdateRecord showing error on parse incoming data

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a .csv file, there is a column call `first_name`, in my UpdateRecord processor I have created a property call `"/first_name" -> value "${field.value:toUpper()}.` But processor is failing to update.

[image]

Comment: Please add an error message

Comment: just remove the wrapper quotes(`"`) of `/first_name` and `${field.value:toUpper()}`. It should work presuming `Record Reader` is set to `CSVReader` and `Record Writer` is set to              `CSVRecordSetWriter`

Comment: There is no error (tony).

Barbaros -> I haven't added any (") in my property name, I have quoted it here just to understand what is my property and value called. For [Record Reader]  I already set it to CSVReader and the same for the writer.

Comment: @samSarker check nifi logs. In the picture, I see an error message (top right corner on the UpdateRecord processor).